# 2nd tier dropdown hides when link clicked - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple Accordion menu: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x3ak0ueg/

When I click `Dropdown 1`, you'll see links appear for `Dropdown` and below that `Test 1` & `Test 2`.
However, `Test` disappears almost instantly. How do I stop this from happening and always show `Test 1` & `Test 2` when `Dropdown 1` is clicked?

In other words, `.sub-menu .sub-menu` is hidden.

Thanks for any help.

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $toggles = $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function () {
        $toggles.not(this).removeClass('selected')
        
        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').next().slideToggle('fast');
        
        //Hide the other panels
        $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
        
    });
});
```

```css
  .accordion-toggle {
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  .sub-menu {
      display: none;
  }
  .sub-menu .sub-menu {
      display: block;
  }
  .selected {
      background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<nav class="medium-8 columns primary menu">
    <ul class="inline naked">
        <li class="primary-item"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress">Home</a></li>      
        <li id="menu-item-74" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74"><a href="#" class="navtoggle">Dropdown 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=45">Dropdown </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-77" class="sub-sub-menu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=47">Test 1</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=49">Test 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>    
            <li id="menu-item-79" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-79"><a href="#" class="navtoggle">Dropdown 2</a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the last line to this

```
$(".sub-menu").not($(this).parent().find('.sub-menu')).slideUp('fast');
```

Which will get the parent `li` of the `a` tag. And make sure that any `.sub-menu` elements within it are not shown. It will still hide any submenus in other `li`s though, which I'm assuming is the intention.

Answer (score 1):

comment this:

```
//$(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
```

Comment: Excellent! If I click `Dropdown 1` then click `Dropdown 2`, should `Dropdown 1` not close? How do I do this too?